# How do I run multiple queries in parallel in java?

Tags: java

I have a `bean` that is getting a lot of information to show on a page.  Each bit of this information is obtained by hitting the `db` and currently this is happening sequentially.  Here is some sample code from my `bean`:

```
int transactionCount = dao.getTransactionCount();
int personCount = dao.getPersonCount();
int carCount = dao.getCarCount();
int houseCount = dao.getHouseCount();
```

I am running `Java 7`.  How could I run this in parallel?  I have looked at the `ExecutorService` and `ForkJoin`, but both seem to have to run the same exact code over and over again.  That is not what I am doing here.  What is the best way to speed this up?

Comment: First things first: is your DAO thread safe?

Comment: You can submit any Callable you want to an ExecutorService.

Comment: My dao is thread safe.

Comment: Does your dao use a separate (new) Connection instance for each request? Otherwise it's not thread-safe, because a single `java.sql.Connection` can not run multiple statements at the same time.

Comment: Why not wrap the three separate queries into a stored procedure and just call that once to get back all the data you need?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can submit different tasks to a single Executor.
You just need to keep the Futures separated to get each task's result:

```
static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);

//start threads
Future<Integer> transactionCountFuture = executor.submit(()-> dao.getTransactionCount());
Future<Integer> personCountFuture = executor.submit(()-> dao.getPersonCount());
Future<Integer> carCountFuture = executor.submit(()-> dao.getCarCount());
Future<Integer> houseCountFuture = executor.submit(()-> dao.getHouseCount());

//wait until all calls returns a result
int transactionCount = transactionCountFuture.get();
int personCount = personCountFuture.get();
int carCountCount = carCountFuture.get();
int houseCount = houseCountFuture.get();
```